# Dynamically obtaining char or int values from enums

Tags: c#, enums

I'm writing a DAL for a project that uses a custom schema in database, with some basic operations: Select, Insert, Update and Delete. Each operation has its corresponding method that receives an Object and these methods extract the information about the tables and columns using Reflection.

Writing the *update* operation, I need to extract some Enum values from properties (some columns has char or int values in database and I'm using Enums to map them inside the system). Here begins my problem:

I wrote a static method to examine each property and its type. If is an Enum, the method have to discover if the Enum has int or char values. I know that any value can be casted to int, but I need the specific char or int to save this value in database.

I tried a lot of casts from other questions from SO, but either the cast doesn't work or the cast throws an exception.

My method is something like this:

```
private IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> ExtractObjectProperties(Object object)
{
    return objeto.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public |
                               BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);
}

protected IEnumerable<OracleParameter> ExtractNonKeyParameters(Object object)
{
    var assembly = Assembly.Load("GN.Portal.Metadata");

    foreach (var propertyInfo in ExtractObjectProperties(object).Where(p => !p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(KeyAttribute), true).Any()))
    {
        var columnAttribute = (ColumnAttribute)propertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ColumnAttribute), true).FirstOrDefault();
        if (columnAttribute != null)
        {
            if (propertyInfo.PropertyType.Namespace != "GN.Portal.MetaData.Enums")
            {
                yield return new OracleParameter
                {
                    ParameterName = columnAttribute.Name,
                    Value = propertyInfo.GetValue(object, null)
                };
            }
            else
            {
                var value = (Enum)Enum.ToObject(assembly.GetType(propertyInfo.PropertyType.FullName), propertyInfo.GetValue(object, null));
                var type = EnumsResolver.Resolve(value.GetType());

                switch (type.Name.ToLower())
                {
                    case "char":
                        yield return new OracleParameter
                        {
                            ParameterName = columnAttribute.Name,
                            Value = /* cast 'value' (Enum) to char here */
                        };
                        break;
                    case "int":
                        yield return new OracleParameter
                        {
                            ParameterName = columnAttribute.Name,
                            Value = /* cast 'value' (Enum) to int here */
                        };
                        break;
                    default:
                        yield return new OracleParameter
                        {
                            ParameterName = columnAttribute.Name,
                            Value = value
                        };
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EnumsResolver is below (it's not a good solution, but I didn't get to think in something better):

```
using System;

namespace GN.Portal.MetaData.Enums
{
    public static class EnumsResolver
    {
        public static Type Resolve(Type type)
        {
            switch (type.Name)
            {
                case "MyEnum1":
                    return typeof (char);
                case "MyEnum2":
                    return typeof (int);
                case "MyEnum3":
                    return typeof (char);
                case "MyEnum4":
                    return typeof (char);
                case "MyEnum5":
                    return typeof (char);
                default:
                    return typeof (string);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I resolve those casts with a good solution?

Comment: Can you show how MyEnum1 and MyEnum2 look like, please?

Comment: Can you tell us what exception you're getting?

Comment: @Magus `Object does not match target type.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of all switch:

```
yield return new OracleParameter
{
    ParameterName = columnAttribute.Name,
    Value = Convert.ChangeType(value, EnumResolver.Resolve(value.GetType());
};
```

Enum Resolver:

```
using System;

namespace GN.Portal.MetaData.Enums
{
    public static class EnumsResolver
    {
        public static Dictionary<Type,List<Type> typeToType = new Dictionary<Type,List<Type>>()
        {
            {typeof(char),new List<Type>{typeof(MyEnum1),typeof(MyEnum3),typeof(MyEnum4),typeof(MyEnum5)}},
            {typeof(int),new List<Type>{typeof(MyEnum2)}}
        };
        public static Type Resolve(Type type)
        {
            IEnumerable<Type> types = typeToType.Where(x => x.Value.Contains(type)).Select(x => x.Key);
            return types.Any() ? types.First() : typeof(string);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `case (typeof(char)):` gives an error: `A constant value is expected`.

Comment: Same error with `typeof(char).AssemblyQualifiedName`: `A constant value is expected`.

Comment: Your `EnumsResolver` has a lot of problems: `Method Add has 2 parameter(s) but is invoked with 5 argument(s).`

Comment: I changed your `IEnumerable<Type> types = typeToType.Where(x => x.Value.Contains(type))` to `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<Type, List<Type>>> types = typeToType.Where(x => x.Value.Contains(type))` because VS was pointing another error. Can you fix the last line, please?

Comment: Thanks but that's not the error, the error was that i didn't add .Select(x => x.Key) in the end

Answer (score 2):

You can get the underlying type of an `enum` using [`Enum.GetUnderlyingType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getunderlyingtype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

To cast it to the right type using [`Convert.ChangeType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtb69x08%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Also of note is `Type.IsEnum` which prevents your need to check the namespace to determine if a type is an enum.

```
if (!propertyInfo.PropertyType.IsEnum)
{
    yield return new OracleParameter
    {
        ParameterName = columnAttribute.Name,
        Value = propertyInfo.GetValue(object, null)
    };
}
else
{
    var enumUnderlyingType = Enum.GetUnderlyingType(propertyInfo.PropertyType);
    var value = propertyInfo.GetValue(objeto, null);

    yield return new OracleParameter 
    {
        ParameterName = columnAttribute.Name,
        Value = Convert.ChangeType(value, enumUnderlyingType)
    };
}
```

Comment: I think that it's not about an underlying type, becase it can't be `char`!

Comment: If he is looking for some unrelated type, he can get the `Type` instance elsewhere.  The conversion still would end up using `Convert.ChangeType`

Comment: I tried this approach and a char value `'V'` appeared as int value 86. I need `'V'` value.

Answer (score 1):

Should be as easy as:

```
public static Type Resolve(Type type)
{
    return Enum.GetUnderlyingType(type);
}
```

And casting could be changed to `Convert.ChangeType` call:

```
else
{
    var value = (Enum)Enum.ToObject(assembly.GetType(propertyInfo.PropertyType.FullName), propertyInfo.GetValue(objeto, null));
    var type = EnumsResolver.Resolve(value.GetType());

    yield return new OracleParameter
    {
        ParameterName = columnAttribute.Name,
        Value = Convert.ChangeType(value, type)
    };
}
```

Comment: The same here. How could it be possibly `char`? It's not a valid underlying type for an enum.